# Connect two subnets via ISP switch

Tags: switch, isp, subnet

I have a wireless router connected to my ISP switch in my home and then a workstation connected to another port on the same switch. Can I somehow connect the two subnets or is that only in the hands of my ISP since the switch is from them?

The switch type is CTS HES-3106 https://www.ctsystem.com/en/product/productdetail.php?fid=12&pid=11

On the wifi subnet, I have i.e. a printer that I would like to use on my Workstation that is on the other subnet and I do not have a wireless adapter on the workstation (well I got one USB adapter but its terribly bad).

Answer (score 1):

This is in your hands, not the ISP and you can do this.

Put your wireless router on the same subnet as your ISP modem / router. This gives you one subnet for all your activities which is very beneficial.

Wireless Router:

1. Connect a LAN port on the Wireless Router to the ISP router.
2. Determine your DCHP Range on the main router and give the Wireless router a Static IP Address on the main router. This prevents it being disconnected and lost if you restart things.
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the wireless router so that you have just one DHCP server.  This is really necessary.

Restart the wireless router and test.

If you make an error or something does not go correctly, you can do a hard reset of the wireless router to factory specifications and try again.

You may also wish to restart the main network to be sure.

I do the above and it works fine. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds fine.  Might also be able to just have the wireless router use "bridge mode" to bridge the WAN port to the set of LAN ports for a similar effect (instead of step number one).